# Restricting Access in ERB code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system, erb

I am trying to build a CMS using ERB.  Is there a way you can give ERB code read-only access to your models?  For instance, I want to be able to load any information on my models (Model.all, Model.find_by_slug, Model.find_by_name, Model.other_model.name, etc...), but I don't want to be able to change this data.  Can you disable ERB from executing commands that would make database changes (Model.save, Model.update, Model.delete, Model.destroy, etc.)???

Comment: Probably not. An often used solution for this is use a dedicated templating language like **liquid**.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? There might be a better way to accomplish your aim.

Comment: I tried liquid and thought it was going to work for me, but I couldn't figure out how to pass arguments to my liquid_methods.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot: http://www.liquidmarkup.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is [safemode](http://github.com/svenfuchs/safemode) by Rails core developer Sven Fuchs to make you erb, well, safer.

A template engine like liquid (which is painful in my eyes) or [mustache](http://github.com/defunkt/mustache) might be easier to learn and apply for your users than erb.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :readonly flag while finding models:

```
@posts = Post.find(:all, :readonly => true)
```

In case you'll try to save it - will throw ReadOnlyRecord exception. But I'd also suggest Liquid as a templater, since user has no restricted access to application varibles inside ERB templates.